# Why is the run button not working in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I have built a code that does not have errors. It has ran on several occasions throughout adding various components, but for some reason, it will not run anymore. When I click the arrow, Eclipse shows the hourglass and then it goes away and does not do anything. How can I make it run so that I can test the program?

Thanks for any helpful assistance.

Comment: Do you see anything in the Error Log? (from memory: Windows -> Views -> Error Log)

Comment: Have you checked output window? May be there is some error or output on that window

Comment: Also don't just resort on the button. Click on the arrow next to the button > Run configurations to have control on what actually you are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that it has been a while since this question was active, however, it has just recently been brought to my attention that I never gave a mark for the correct answer. The answer to the question was that there was a configuration error that was causing the compiler to stop whenever I pressed the run button. It was solved by a classmate that was not on this forum. Thanks to everyone who assisted. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try running it in debug mode, with a breakpoint at the very start of your main() function.

If it doesn't stop at the breakpoint, then you'll know its not the code, and is probably your Run configurations as dimitrisli pointed out.

If it does stop, then you can step through the code and see what's causing it to exit early.

I've also noticed that if you have the console selected while clicking run, instead of the code, it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an uncaught exception somewhere in the program, most probably a NullPointerException that will not be visible if you do not do anything within the catch block after a try block

Try this: After every try block in your program, write

`catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}`

This should bring you some output from the console. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me to, with both the button and `Run->run`. When this starts happening I have to bring up the run `configuration menu` and press `run` from there then it will run. It doesn't seem to be a matter of their being errors or not, and it's somewhat frustraiting to sometimes have to open the configuration window every time until I restart or something